# moving objects in nsmutablearray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

i have an NSMutableArray;

```
NSMutableArray
--NSMutableArray
----NSDictionary
----NSDictionary
----NSDictionary
--NSMutableArray
----NSDictionary
----NSDictionary
----NSDictionary
```

i want to move first NSDictionary to second NSMutableArray.
here is the code:

```
id tempObject = [[tableData objectAtIndex:fromSection] objectAtIndex:indexOriginal];
[[tableData objectAtIndex:fromSection] removeObjectAtIndex:indexOriginal];
[[tableData objectAtIndex:toSection] insertObject:tempObject atIndex:indexNew];
```

it removes the object but cant insert the object to new position.
the error is:

```
[CFDictionary retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4c45110
```

in header file:

```
NSMutableArray *tableData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tableData;
```

how can i reorder/move the objects in nsmutablearray?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an object is removed from a mutable array, it is send a `release` message. Thus, if nothing else holds references to it, the object will be deallocated.

So you can simply reorder the statements:

```
[[tableData objectAtIndex:toSection] insertObject:tempObject atIndex:indexNew];
[[tableData objectAtIndex:fromSection] removeObjectAtIndex:indexOriginal];
```

... or explicitly keep the object alive:

```
[tempObject retain];
[[tableData objectAtIndex:fromSection] removeObjectAtIndex:indexOriginal];
[[tableData objectAtIndex:toSection] insertObject:tempObject atIndex:indexNew];
[tempObject release];
```

Read through [Array Fundamentals](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW1) and [Mutable Arrays](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW2) for more details.